# Update attachment ID after transfer

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, transfer, media-library

Im working on transferring a site that has a massive amount of images. So had to resort to FTP method to move the images from the one site to the new host enviorment. That part has went smoothly and can see the images in the new sites media library.

The issue that im having now is that the old site has a custom post type that includes a gallery. This Gallery saves the images in a json array with the atachements (images) ID's. So now when importing these custom post to the new site I cant get the images to match any more because the atachemtent IDs does not match any more.

I have tried using multiple media library tools, even the base Wordpress Export and import tool, to maybe get the IDs to match but with no luck. I do know that it might not even be posible because of the why the IDs is assigned.

Is there maybe a tool that method that could help match the ids between the 2 sites or update the old site ids with the new ones?

Comment: When you say "transferring a site", does that mean 1:1, or are you trying to add new content into an already existing site?

Comment: It is adding the content into the existing site.

Comment: All of it? Then I'd use a plugin such a WP Migrate DB, to make sure you import not only the CPTs, but also the attachment posts representing those images.

Comment: Will give it a shot to transfer the attachment post for the images. Did try using another plugin to do the same thing but ended up just causing more problems. Thanks